# 3 steps back at the end of Kaddish Yatom or Kaddish DeRabbanan?

Tags: kaddish

Is their a source for the custom by some of taking 3 steps back at the end of Kaddish Yatom or Kaddish DeRabbanan?

Comment: Adi.Haramati, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Having more than one version of a question is quite useful, since it makes it more likely that people will find our post on the matter with whatever search terms they use. I hope to see you around!